# Price Ranges in Magento

Tags: magento, layered-navigation

By default the layered navigation in Magento shows me in the price attribute

From 0 to 1000
From 1001 to 2000
etc, etc.

Is it possible to change this either by configuration or by code?
If it has to be by code can you please provide code example and which file(s) do I need to modify.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Go to

> System > Configuration > Catalog > "Layered navigation" section > "Price Navigation Step Calculation"

set "*Price Navigation Step Calculation*" to **Manual** and change the settings that appear.

"*Default Price Navigation Step*" is a *range*. E.g. if we set it 500 then the price ranges will be like:

> - 0 - 500
> - 500 - 1000
> - 1000 - 1500
> - 1500 - 2000 etc..

In "*Maximum Number of Price Intervals*" if we put 3 then the price ranges will be like:

> - 0 - 500
> - 500 - 1000
> - 1000 and above

Comment: you need to go
System > Configuration > Catalog > "Layered navigation" section > "Price Navigation Step Calculation"
In Magento version 1.7.0.2