# Price Filter not working in Magento 1.9.2.4 Community Edition

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I have followed two tutorials to do this task in Magento, but it is not working,

http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-configure-the-price-filter-for-layered-navigation.html

[Price Ranges in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713009/price-ranges-in-magento)

I am sharing my setting of **system -> configuration -> catalog -> layered navigation**

[image]

Here is my price attribute settings:

[image]

[image]

This is my frontend display:

[image]

One more thing when I am setting **Use In Search Results Layered Navigation as yes** under price attribute setting price filter is visible on search result.
see the screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `is_anchor` true for your CATEGORY1, refresh cache and see the results - `Catalog->Manage Categories->CATEGORY1->Display Settings`: `Is Anchor -> Yes`